# ¿Cómo imprimir en pdf los resultados de una búsqueda en ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, rotativa

Soy nuevo en ASP.NET MVC y estoy tratando de imprimir los registros filtrados entre dos fechas en un PDF. Estoy usando ROTATIVA para generar el PDF, el problema es que el PDF se genera correctamente pero con todos los registros y no solo con el resultado del filtro de registros por las dos fechas.

Código para el controlador:

```
//this method is for put the list of the records on the view
public ActionResult SaleList()
{
    using (inventoryEntitiesDBA dc = new inventoryEntitiesDBA())
    {
        return View(dc.sales.ToList());
    }
}

//this method is to filter the records between start and end date

public ActionResult SaleList(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    bool Status = false;
    if(ModelStatus.IsValid())
    {
        using(inventoryEntitiesDBA dc = new inventoryEntitiesDBA())
        {
             var d = dc.sales.Where(x => x.sale_day >= start && x.sale_day <= end).ToList();
          
             Status = true;

             ViewBag.Status = Status;

             return View(d);
        }
    } 
}

//this method is to generate the PDF
public ActionResult SalesToPdf()
{
    var report = new ActionAsPdf("SaleList");

    return report;
}
```

Código de la vista:

```
 @if (ViewBag.Status != null && Convert.ToBoolean(ViewBag.Status))
 {
   //this is for print if the method for filter
   //the dates are called
   <p align="right">
       @Html.ActionLink("Generate PDF", "SalesToPdf2")
   </p>
 }
 else
 {
   //this is for print if the method for filter the dates are not called
   <p align="right">
        @Html.ActionLink("Generate PDF", "SalesToPdf")
   </p>
 }

  <center>
  @using (Html.BeginForm("SaleList", "Sales", FormMethod.Post))
  {
    
      <span>Start Date </span> <input type="date" name="start" />
      <span> End Date </span><input type="date" name="end" />
      <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
   }
   </center>
```

No sé exactamente qué hacer, se agradece cualquier sugerencia.

*Actualización: creé otra acción que recibe los datos de las fechas desde la
vista `SaleList` debido a que el método para generar el PDF al parecer solo llamaba a la acción que muestra todos los registros.

```
    public ActionResult SaleList2(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        bool Status = false;

        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (inventoryEntitiesDBA dc = new inventoryEntitiesDBA())
            {
                var d = dc.sales.Where(x => x.sale_day >= start && x.sale_day <= end).ToList();

                Status = true;

                ViewBag.Status = Status;

                return View(d);
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Acción para generar el PDF:

```
    public ActionResult SalesToPdf2(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        var reporte = new ActionAsPdf("SaleList2", new {start, end});

        return reporte;
    }
```

Y en la vista:

```
<center>
@using (Html.BeginForm("SalesToPdf2", "Caja", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <span>Fecha de inicio </span> <input type="date" name="start" />
    <span> Fecha de fin </span><input type="date" name="end" />
    <input type="submit" value="Buscar" />
}
</center>
```

Ahora, teniendo el código de esta forma el PDF se genera con los registros filtrados, pero se genera de una vez que se da click en "Buscar". Sin embargo, la duda que me surge es ¿cómo se puede hacer lo anterior pero que los resultados de los registros filtrados se puedan visualizar y que si se desea se genere el PDF? es decir que el PDF no se genere luego de que se de click en "Buscar".

*ACTUALIZACIÓN

Usando el `ViewBag` para enviar las fechas a la vista.

-Código de la vista A: aquí se envían las fechas y el controlador `SalesList2` filtra y devuelve los registros resultantes

```
<center>
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaleList2", "Caja", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <span>Fecha de inicio </span> <input type="date" name="start" />

    <span> Fecha de fin </span><input type="date" name="end" />

    <input type="submit" value="Buscar" />
}
</center>
```

-Código del controlador `SalesList2`

```
    public ActionResult SalesList2(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        bool Status = false;

        DateTime st = start;

        DateTime en = end;

        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (inventoryEntitiesDBA dc = new inventarioEntitiesDBA())
            {
                var d = dc.sales.Where(x => x.sale_day >= start && x.sale_day <= end).ToList();

                Status = true;

                ViewBag.Status = Status;

                ViewBag.st = st; //Se envía los datos de las fechas a través del ViewBag

                ViewBag.en = en; //Se envía los datos de las fechas a través del ViewBag

                return View(d);
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

-Código de la vista B:

```
<center>
@using (Html.BeginForm("SalesList2", "Caja", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <span>Fecha de inicio </span> <input type="date" name="start" />

    <span> Fecha de fin </span><input type="date" name="end" />

    <input type="submit" value="Buscar" />
}
</center>

<div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("SalesToPdf2", "Caja", FormMethod.Post))
{
    DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(ViewBag.st);

    DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime(ViewBag.en);

    <input type="date" value="@Convert.ToDateTime(ViewBag.st)" hidden="hidden"/> //Aquí se supone que se enviaría lo que está en el ViewBag

    <input type="date" value="@Convert.ToDateTime(ViewBag.en)" hidden="hidden"/> //Aquí se supone que se enviaría lo que está en el ViewBag

    <div align="right">
        <input type="submit" value="PDF" />
    </div>
}
</div>
```

Teniendo lo anterior cuando se pulsa el botón para generar el PDF me tira error de NULL. No sé si el manejo del ViewBag sea así como lo estoy haciendo, pero puse unos breakpoints para mirar lo que llegaba en el controlador y resuta que si llegan los datos correctamente.

Comment: Veamos si entiendo. Tienes una vista `A `con un formulario para  ingresar fecha `start` y fecha `end` al presionar el botón `buscar` quieres que te redirija a la vista `B` donde están los datos filtrados y en esa vista `B` quieres un botón para poder imprimir el PDF ?

Comment: Si, exacto, pues con la sugerencia que ya me brindó es posible generar el PDF, pero de manera inmediata al pulsar el botón para filtrar.

Comment: Entonces en la vista B debe haber un botón para imprimir  el reporte en PDF. Se puede poner en otro form con los campos start y end de tipo hidden. Así al presionar el botón se enviaran las fechas del filtro. La vista B ya recibe ambas fechas así que esas mismas se pueden poner en los campos hidden. Y la vista A llamará a la vista B.

Comment: Si, entiendo el método, pero no entiendo muy bien cómo se mandarían los datos de la fecha a los campos hidden, es decir el otro form iría en la vista B y una vez mandandados las fechas para el filtro de la vista A a la vista B, en los campos hidden del otro form llegarían "automáticamente"?

Comment: La vista `B` recibe las fechas ( en su controlador ), las fechas se ponen en un `ViewBag` y de ahí se toman los valores para los campos hidden del form.

Comment: A los campos `hidden` debes ponerles el atributo  `name` ( si los input de un form no tienen name no se envían ) y el valor del `name` debe ser igual a los parámetros que se esperan en `SalesToPdf2` (start y end ).

Comment: Ya hice los cambios pero sigue tirándome el error de NULL.

Comment: `SalesToPdf2` está recibiendo los parámetros start y end?

Comment: Pues al parecer no, porque aún me tira el error en la vista de NULL, en la actualización que puse cree estas variables en la vista B para ver si a través de ellas las fechas llegaban: `DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(ViewBag.st);`. La variable `start` es la que pongo en el valor del `name` en el `input`. Viendo el código cuando lo ejecuto en los breakpoints todo parece correcto. El error completo: https://ibb.co/7zgqDNJ

Comment: En la vista `B` en el form que llama a `SalesToPdf2`, donde están los `hidden`, a esos hidden debes ponerles el `name` start y end. Deben quedar así: `<input type="hidden" value="@Convert.ToDateTime(ViewBag.st)"  name="start"/>`

Comment: Agregué una actualización en la respuesta  agregando los datos al ViewBag y creando los inputs hidden en la vista B.

Comment: Ok funciona, solamente tuve que poner la línea de `<input type="hidden" value="@Convert.ToDateTime(ViewBag.st)"  name="start"/>` junto a las líneas que puso en la actualización, sinceramente agradezco sus respuestas he aprendido bastante con esta consulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La acción `SalesToPdf` debe recibir los parámetros de fecha inicio y fin y a la función `ActionAsPdf()`se le tiene que pasar un objeto que lleve esos parámetros.

```
public ActionResult SalesToPdf(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    var report = new ActionAsPdf("SaleList", new {start, end});

    return report;
}
```

El formulario debe llamar la acción `SalesTopdf`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SalesToPdf", "Sales", FormMethod.Post))
      {
        
          <span>Start Date </span> <input type="date" name="start" />
          <span> End Date </span><input type="date" name="end" />
          <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
       }
```

---

**Actualización**

```
public ActionResult SalesList2(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        bool Status = false;

        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (inventoryEntitiesDBA dc = new inventarioEntitiesDBA())
            {
                var d = dc.sales.Where(x => x.sale_day >= start && x.sale_day <= end).ToList();

                Status = true;

                ViewBag.Status = Status;

                ViewBag.start = start; //Se envía los datos de las fechas a través del ViewBag

                ViewBag.end = end; //Se envía los datos de las fechas a través del ViewBag

                return View(d);
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Vista B:

Se usa el helper `Html.Hidden()` para crear un input tipo hidden. Recibe como parámetro el nombre del input y  busca en el `ViewBag` si hay alguna clave con ese nombre y toma el valor automáticamente.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SalesToPdf2", "Caja", FormMethod.Post))
{

    @Html.Hidden("start")
    @Html.Hidden("end")
    
    <div align="right">
        <input type="submit" value="PDF" />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, ya lo intenté con las indicaciones que me brindó, pero aún sigue imprimiéndome todos los registros y no solo los que se le aplican el filtro según la fecha. Además en la parte de la vista las fechas deben llegar al método `SaleList` para que haga el filtro y devuelva en la vista los registros filtrados, entonces ahí es donde se debería poder pasar a PDF los registros. Intenté poner ambos métodos en la vista (`Html.BeginForm("SalesToPdf", "SalesToPdf2", "Sales", FormMethod.Post)`), pero me tira error de que no encuentra la página.

Comment: En el código que puse ya hace lo del filtro y muestra en una vista dichos resultados del filtro, pero no logro que se pase a PDF solo los registros filtrados. Cualquier sugerencia es agradecida.

Comment: Entiendo, `SalesList` funciona al llamarlo directamente y regresa sus registros filtrados. Lo que sucede es que `SalesToPdf` es quien va a llamar a `SalesList`. O sea que la vista generada por `SalesList` es tomada por `ActionAsPdf()` y ahí se convierte en PDF. Por eso la secuencia es primero llamar a `SalesToPdf` con  las fechas y `SalesToPdf` llamará a `SalesList` y le pasará las fechas para filtrar.

Comment: Ok, ya revisé mejor y parece funcionar, es decir si me genera el pdf solo con los datos del filtro, pero me surge una duda y es si en lugar de que se genere el PDF inmediatamente, ¿cómo puedo poner los resultados del filtro en la vista y luego si se desea que se de click y ahí si generar el PDF? 
Pd: gracias por la explicación.

Comment: Sí se puede. Solo debes ordenar los pasos. Si quieres ver los datos en la vista llama a la acción `SalesList` y cuando los quieras imprimir llamas a `SalesToPdf`.

Comment: Ok, pero ahora me aparece el siguiente error: `El diccionario de parámetros contiene una entrada NULL para el parámetro 'start' del tipo que no acepta valores NULL...` y bueno creería que es por qué desde la vista no le llega nada para que mande a método, la verdad no sé exactamente cómo enviarle los datos necesarios desde la vista a parte de lo que ya he mostrado.

Comment: Cuál acción estás llamando?

Comment: Lo que hice para que funcionara con las sugerencias que me brindó fue crear otra vista que devuelve solo los resultados del filtro, así que desde la vista "principal" `SalesList` se ponen las fechas, se da en el botón para filtrar y la acción `SalesToPdf` recibe los valores y llama a la segunda vista "SalesList2" e imprime lo que haya ahí. Para hacerlo de forma que se pueda ver los resultados del filtro, y que luego si se quiere se pase a PDF, creé un botón donde llama a `SalesToPdf` desde la vista `SalesList2` y ahí es donde aparece el error.

Comment: No hay problema, aquí  el objetivo es que los problemas queden resueltos. Si quieres actualiza tu pregunta y agrega lo que has hecho con su explicación para revisarlo. No borres lo que ya está solo agrega lo nuevo para no perder la historia.